# Kafka Consumer and Producer

Tags: apache-kafka

Can I have the consumer act as a producer(publisher) as well? I have a user case where a consumer (C1) polls a topic and pulls messages. after processing the message and performing a commit, it needs to notify another process to carry on remaining work. Given this use case is it a valid design  for Consumer (C1) to publish a message to a different topic? i.e. C1 is also acting as a producer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a valid use case. We have many production applications does the same, consuming events from a source topic, perform data enrichment/transformation and publish the output into another topic for further processing.

Again, the implementation pattern depends on which tech stack you are using. But if you after Spring Boot application, you can have look at https://medium.com/geekculture/implementing-a-kafka-consumer-and-kafka-producer-with-spring-boot-60aca7ef7551

Comment: Thx for the quick response. We are using Spring Boot app. I will look at the article you posted.  A related question I have is as follows. What happens if the duration of  "data enrichment/transformation" in your case exceeds the poll interval? i.e. if the process post consumption happens to be a long running one?

Comment: Tweak your consumer configuration appropriately under a load testing..We do  have a variety of applications and these values differ in use case. If you are sure the data processing is going to take more time than the default values (say 5 secs per batch of records per poll()), then you need to alter the values to a higher side. In most of our cases  we have consumer.pause() and .resume() for longer running batches to refrain from timeouts, but it is not recommended now. Eventually, your consumer will be controlled by max.poll.records, max.poll.timeout.ms and session.timeout parameters.

Comment: Most of the consumer/producer configuration parameters have reasonable defaults and do not require modification. And again, it depends on your business requirement.

Comment: Kindly mark this as correct answer, if you believe it is useful, so that others can use this as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Totally valid scenario, for example you can have connector source or a producer which simple push raw data to a topic.

The receiver is loosely coupled to your publisher so they cannot communicate each other directly.

Then you need C1 (Mediator) to consume message from the source, transform the data and publish the new data format to a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a JVM based client, this is precisely the use case for using Kafka Streams rather than the base Consumer/Producer API.

Kafka Streams applications must consume from an initial topic, then can convert(map), filter, aggregate, split, etc into other topics.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/